# Where is Twitter App Source Code

Tags: android

One of the design sessions from Google I/O this year showcased this app as an example of putting their design principles to good use.  They said it would be open sourced but I'm having trouble finding it.

Comment: I want the source code to aid me in learning how to write better android apps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has not been released yet, as far as we are aware.